# Slice a multidimensional pytorch tensor based on values in other tensors

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization, slice, numpy-slicing

I have 4  PyTorch tensors:

- `data` of shape `(l, m, n)`
- `a` of shape `(k,)` and datatype `long`
- `b` of shape `(k,)` and datatype `long`
- `c` of shape `(k,)` and datatype `long`

I want to slice the tensor `data` such that it picks the element addressed by `a` in `0th` dimension. In the `1st` and `2nd` dimensions, I want to pick a patch of values based on the element addressed by `b` and `c`. Specifically, I want to pick 9 values - a `3x3` patch around the value addressed by `b`. Thus my sliced tensor should have a shape `(k, 3, 3)`.

MWE:

```
data = torch.arange(200).reshape((2, 10, 10))
a = torch.Tensor([1, 0, 1, 1, 0]).long()
b = torch.Tensor([5, 6, 3, 4, 7]).long()
c = torch.Tensor([4, 3, 7, 6, 5]).long()

data1 = data[a, b-1:b+1, c-1:c+1]  # gives error

>>> TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index
```

Expected output

```
data1[0] = [[143,144,145],[153,154,155],[163,164,165]]
data1[1] = [[52,53,54],[62,63,64],[72,73,74]]
data1[2] = [[126,127,128],[136,137,138],[146,147,148]]
and so on
```

How can I do this without using for loop?

PS:

- I've padded `data` to make sure that the locations addressed by `a,b,c` are within the limit.
- I don't need gradients to flow through this operation. So, I can convert these to NumPy and slice if that is faster. But I would prefer a solution in PyTorch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first expand the indices and then add shifts to the repeated indices. Note that the shift for the row and column should be reversed. For example,

```
import torch

data = torch.arange(200).reshape((2, 10, 10))
a = torch.Tensor([1, 0, 1, 1, 0]).long()
b = torch.Tensor([5, 6, 3, 4, 7]).long()
c = torch.Tensor([4, 3, 7, 6, 5]).long()

index1 = a.repeat_interleave(9) # kernel_size^2

index2 = b.repeat_interleave(9) # kernel_size^2
shift = torch.arange(-1, 2).repeat_interleave(3).repeat(5) # Shape: (kernel_size^2 x 5) -> [-1, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1]
shifted_index2 = index2 + shift

index3 = c.repeat_interleave(9) 
shift = torch.arange(-1, 2).repeat(3).repeat(5) # Shape: (kernel_size^2 x 5) -> [-1,  0,  1, -1,  0,  1, -1,  0,  1]
shifted_index3 = index3 + shift

# Use the indexing arrays to select the patches
data1 = data[index1, shifted_index2, shifted_index3].view(5, 3, 3)

print(data1[0])
print(data1[1])
print(data1[2])
```

The output:

```
tensor([[143, 144, 145],
        [153, 154, 155],
        [163, 164, 165]])
tensor([[52, 53, 54],
        [62, 63, 64],
        [72, 73, 74]])
tensor([[126, 127, 128],
        [136, 137, 138],
        [146, 147, 148]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with `slice` although there is a list comprehension at the end. However, it is a loop of only k elements.

```py
import numpy as np 

a = torch.IntTensor([1, 0, 1, 1, 0]).long()
b = torch.IntTensor([5, 6, 3, 4, 7]).long()
c = torch.IntTensor([4, 3, 7, 6, 5]).long()
data = torch.arange(200).reshape((2, 10, 10))

a = list(slice(val, val+1)   for val in a)
b = list(slice(val-1, val+2) for val in  b)
c = list(slice(val-1, val+2) for val in  c)

data1 = [data[a_, b_, c_] for a_, b_, c_ in zip(a,b,c)]
```